# Bicycles and spanning trees of graphs

Tags: algebraic-graph-theory, graph-theory

A *spanning tree* in a graph is a connected spanning subgraph with no cycles; it is well known that the number of spanning trees can be found by taking the determinant of a certain matrix related to the graph.

A *cycle* in a graph (note: not quite usual definition) is a set of edges such that every vertex is incident with an even number of the edges, and a *cocycle* in a graph is a set of edges that forms an edge cutset. A *bicycle* is a set of edges that is simultaneously a cycle and a cocycle.

These concepts are best thought of in terms of the vector space $V = GF(2)^{E(G)}$ where a set of edges is identified with the support of a vector in $V$; if $B$ is the vertex-edge incidence matrix of the graph $G$ then the cocycles are all the vectors in the row-space of $B$, while the cycles are all the vectors in the dual of the row-space of $B$ and the bicycles are the vectors in the intersection of these subspaces.

Therefore a graph always has $2^b$ bicycles for some $b = b(G)$ (and, for those who are interested, this number $2^b$ is given by $\pm T(-1,-1)$ where $T$ is the Tutte polynomial of $G$).

If the number of spanning trees of a graph is odd, then it has no non-zero bicycles and $b=0$. More generally it has been known for a long time that the number of bicycles is a *divisor* of the number of spanning trees of $G$. All the proofs that I know of this fact are *algebraic* and based on messing around with a matrix or something essentially equivalent.

**Question**: Is there a *combinatorial interpretation* or *combinatorial proof* of the fact that the number of spanning trees in a graph is a multiple of $2^{b(G)}$?

For example, if we could clump the spanning trees together into sets of size $2^{b(G)}$ by using the bicycles somehow.

**Sub-question**: Is there any interpretation of the quotient (i.e. number of spanning trees divided by $2^{b(G)}$)?

Comment: So the bicycle space is the hull of the cycle space.  Is there a standard basis for the bicycle space analogous to a set of fundamental cycles for the cycle space?

Btw, the cocycle space is not all edge-cutsets but only the sets of edges which cross some cut.

Comment: Yes, you are right about the edge-cuts.  As for a standard basis, there is one for plane graphs given by Shank's theory of "left-right paths" - walk around the edges of the graph turning alternately left and right at each vertex until you come back to the beginning, forming a closed trail. Edges traversed in only one direction in this trail form a bicycle. Repeat until every edge has been traversed once in each direction. The resulting set of bicycles then covers every bicycle-edge exactly twice, and is therefore not linearly independent, but throw any one out and you get a basis.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but re the sentence "If the number of spanning trees is odd then $b=0$": this is actually if and only if. See e.g. my unpublished paper from 1996, http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/pubs/Epp-TR-96-14.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

The number of spanning trees of a plane(ly embedded) graph can be obtained from the Tutte polynomial.

(Pardon the proof via knot theory:  the Jones polynomial of an alternating knot diagram is a specialization of the Tutte polynomial of an associated plane graph, and the Jones polynomial evaluated at -1 gives the number of spanning trees.)

For non-plane graphs, it may be possible to use the Bollobas-Riordan-Tutte polynomial.  See for example:  "The Jones polynomial and graphs on surfaces" by Dasbach, David Futer, Kalfagianni, Lin, Stoltzfus.

Thus I would expect such a proof to lie entirely within calculations of the Tutte polynomial.

Comment: This does not answer the question. It is well understood that the Tute polynomial determines the number of spanning trees.